# Fire onSelectAll callback of antd table manually

Tags: reactjs, antd

What I want to achieve is to fire the deselection of all the rows when the user clicks a button, as in this example:

[image]

When a user clicks on the "Anular selección" all the rows should be deselected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a state which keeps track of the selectedRowKeys and pass it to the `selectedRowKeys` props provided by antd .

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/selection-antd4169-forked-x5q73?file=/index.js)

[Selection Props API](https://ant.design/components/table/#rowSelection)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the content of your selectedRowKeys at clicking "Anular seleccion" and all the checked rows going to uncheck.

```
const { selectedRowKeys } = this.state;

const rowSelection = {
  selectedRowKeys,
  },
};
```

...

```
 <Table
       rowSelection={rowSelection}
       ...
```